# Row level operation only works sometimes in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to create a function in Numpy that standardizes the values in every column(transposed to rows). The issue I am having is that some simple operations work while others that should also work don't.

Here is an example function of what I am trying to get working. I have commented the lines that work and don't work.

```py
def standardize(features):
    for feature in features.T:
        #feature = (feature - feature.mean()) / feature.std()
        feature = feature*2 # <--- Doesn't work
        feature *=2 # <--- works
    return features
```

features is an NxM matrix.

The line that is commented out is the only one I need for the function to work. It performs the operations on each feature but when I return features, it just returns the input.

The next two examples I have included that show the code that works and the code that doesn't work. (Note: I've been commenting one out while I run the other one for testing it)

I have trouble understanding why one works and the other doesn't. Are they not essentially the same thing?

Comment: This has nothing to do with numpy. By using `feature = feature * 2`, you simply set the reference of the *local variable*, not the item of the array.

Comment: That being said, you can just use `return 2 * features.T`, this is more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case (`feature = feature * 2`), you simply construct a *new* numpy array, and you set the *local* variable `feature` to that new numpy array, but that does not mean you update where `feature` was referring to originally.

In the latter, you perform an inplace update, and thus you update that slice of the numpy array itself. It would be equivalent to writing `features[i] *= 2`, with `i` an index of the row you want to update.

Note that you furthermore will *not* transpose the numpy array inline, since you work on a view that is a transposed view of the original matrix.

Anyway, calculating the Z-score in bulk per column can be done more efficiently by calculating the `mean` and the `std` per column:

```
def standardize(features):
    return (features - features.mean(axis=0))/features.std(axis=0)
```

Furthermore you can use [`scipy`'s **`scipy.stat.zscore`** [scipy-doc]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.zscore.html) that will do the work for you.